# How to kill a process when I cant kill it via the GUI and kill in the terminal?

Tags: skype

I have some weird Skype crashes today. If I try to close it via the X nothing happens. I tried to kill the process over the KDE Process Manager (<kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd>+<kbd>`ESC`</kbd>).

I even tried to kill Skype via the terminal:

```
killall skype
kill (skypes process number)
```

None of the both worked. Right now I got to relogin to get it working again, and it keeps crashing every 15mins. I'm using KDE 4.7 and Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

These days killall will also let you pass in a signal (to save you needing to look up a PID):

```
killall -9 skype
```

Comment: doesnt work for skype ATM: `skype: no process found`

Comment: You should have to sure with process name, or use process id instead `$(pgrep skype)`

Answer (score 20):

use this :

`kill -9 $(pgrep skype)`

Comment: Instead of looking for the pid, use `kill -9 $(pgrep skype)`.

Answer (score 4):

To kill a process/application in a Terminal type

```
$ ps -e | grep skype
```

this will show the skype process ID

e.g, it shows,

```
2338 ?        00:00:33 skype
```

type

```
$ kill 2338
```

in GUI configure a short cut key for *xKill*, (like I have configured to Ctrl + Alt + Bkspace)  once you will press the combination, you will get a small cross symbol *X* instead of mouse cursor .... select the application window with that cross cursor with mouse and it will kill that application.

Comment: man there are much faster ways. these aren't 90s anymore :D

Answer (score 1):

I automated all this:

1. Made a `stop-skype.sh` file which contained:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    #stop-skype.sh
    kill $(ps aux | grep '[s]kype' | awk '{print $2}')
```

2. Made this file executeable
3. In `/usr/share/applications`, made `skype-shutdown.desktop` containing:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Skype Shutdown
Comment=Shut down Skype running in the background
Exec=/home/volker/stop-skype.sh
Icon=/home/volker/stop-skype.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Application;
```

4. Made a `stop-skype.png` file which you can download from
   http://www.freemed.info/.download/stop-skype.png
5. Opened Files and dragged the `/usr/share/applications/skype-shutdown.desktop` to Cairo Dock.

This resulted in an icon on which one can click to stop all Skype processes.

See: http://www.freemed.info/.download/Skype-shutdown.png

Answer (score 0):

```
kill -9 `ps -ef |grep skype | awk {print'$2'}`
```

Because

1. `ps -ef` lists all proccess .
2. `grep skype` filters only skype proccess
3. `awk {print'$2'}` retrieves the 2nd column of output which is `PID`

Answer (score -1):

Create a bat-file and put this in:

taskkill /f /im "SkypeApp.exe" /im "Skype.exe" /im "SkypeBackgroundHost.exe" /im "SkypeBridge.exe"

Open task scheduler and create a task on logon with 1 minute delay and link it to the bat-file.

After restart roll-over the skype icon and it will disappear (it's a refresh :)

Comment: Please do correct me if I'm misunderstanding, but this appears to be about how to solve the problem on Windows rather than Ubuntu!